# Fullscreen Mode Android Studio black stripe at the top

Tags: android, kotlin, fullscreen

I want to do full screen in the app
I did it with this code

```
`private fun hideSystemUI() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
private fun showSystemUI() {
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)`
```

But I have a camera on the screen and I see a
[black bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhDto.jpg).
How to stretch the screen so that this bar is not there

Kotlin programming language
Thank You Very Much

Answer (score 5):

this problem happen with me for 2 different devices and this because of the front camera notch or screen cutout.

I used this code in oncreate() :

```
hideSystemUI();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) { 
getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES; }
```

Or in the theme style xml file add this line :

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go into the theme file and change your theme to `"Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//will hide the title   
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```